# Sequential user input stored in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, dialog, user-input

Is there a way to prompt a user, using consecutive JOptionPane Input Dialog's, for consecutive array input storages? Maybe I'm not great at asking the question, so please refer to the following example...

```
  titleInputs[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a book title, or zzz to    
      quit:");
  authorInputs[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter " + titleInputs[x] + "'s 
      author's last name, or zzz to quit: ")
  pageInputs[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter " + titleInputs[x] + "'s page 
      count, or zzz to quit: ")
```

Can you find the first titleInput, followed by another inputDialog asking for author, and lastly followed by pageCount? All while referring to the initial title for the selection in which you're querying?

The following are the desired outcome:
   For title #1
      Please enter a title:
      Please enter "title's" author:
      Please enter "title's" page count:
   For title #2
      Please enter a title:
      Please enter "title's" author:
      Please enter "title's" page count:
...continue until all 5 titles are collected...

Comment: I am struggling to understand the question

Comment: You could use a loop, increase `x` for each iteration.

Comment: Maybe create a class `Book` with all these attributes and store them in an array of `Book`s? Not sure whether I understood you correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int x = 0;
string currTitle = "";
do
{
  currTitle = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a book title, or zzz to quit:");
  if(!currTitle.equals("zzz"))
  {
    titleInputs[x] = currTitle;
    authorInputs[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter " + titleInputs[x] + "'s author's last name: ");
    pageInputs[x] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter " + titleInputs[x] + "'s page count: ");
    x = x+1;
  }
} while(!currTitle.equals("zzz")) //if you wanted, you could do: while(!currTitle.equals("zzz") && x < MAX_ARRAY_SIZE) ...obviously after declaring MAX_ARRAY_SIZE somewhere.
```

Comment: you still need to declare the arrays (`titleInputs`, `authorInputs`, etc) but I believe you just need to loop like this.

Comment: @user3304613 also might want to include the maximum array size in the `while()` check.

Comment: I have the max array size to 5, not included in code snip on here...but thanks for the input!